# Dropdown Menu in Navbar and Homepage Content Not Displaying Properly After Page Refresh in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm encountering an issue with the display of the dropdown menu in the navbar and the content of the homepage after refreshing the page in my JavaScript-based web application. Upon initial login, the navbar and homepage content render correctly. However, after refreshing the page, the dropdown menu in the navbar disappears, and the homepage content fails to display as expected.

I have implemented a token verification functionality that checks the user's token validity on each page refresh. While this functionality works as intended, it seems to interfere with the proper rendering of the navbar dropdown menu and homepage content after the page is refreshed.

that is the code for the verification

```
import Navigate from "../Components/Router/Navigate";

const {refreshUser, isAuthenticated} = require("./auths");

/**
 * Check if the token is still valid by sending a request to the server
 */
async function checkTokenValidity() {
  if(isAuthenticated()){
    // get the token from the authenticated user
    const token  = sessionStorage.getItem('token') || localStorage.getItem('token');
    try {
      // send a request to the server to check if the token is still valid
      const response = await fetch(`${process.env.API_BASE_URL}/auths/refresh`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `${token}`
        }
      });
  
      if (!response.ok) {
        // if the response is not ok, token is not valid anymore 
        Navigate('/logout');
      }else{
        const user = await response.json();
        refreshUser(user);
      }

    } catch (error) {
      Navigate('/');
    }

  }
}

export default checkTokenValidity;
```

and i call it in index.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './stylesheets/main.css';
import './stylesheets/vendor.css';

import Navbar from './Components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Router from './Components/Router/Router';
import  checkTokenValidity  from './utils/session';

await checkTokenValidity();

Navbar();

Router();
```

that is the code of the navbar

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import { Navbar as BootstrapNavbar } from 'bootstrap';
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import $ from 'jquery';
import { getAuthenticatedUser, isAuthenticated } from '../../utils/auths';
import Navigate from '../Router/Navigate';
import logoImage from '../../img/icon.jpg'


// const SITE_NAME = 'Stagify';

const Navbar = () => {
  renderNavbar();
};

function renderNavbar() {
  const authenticatedUser = getAuthenticatedUser();

  const anonymousUserNavbar = `
    <div class="navigation-wrap bg-light start-header start-style px-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/" target="_blank"><img src="${logoImage}" alt=""></a>    
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto py-4 py-md-0">
                                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-uri="/login">Se connecter</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`;

  const authenticatedUserNavbar = `
  <div class="navigation-wrap bg-light start-header start-style px-4" >
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/" target="_blank"><img src="${logoImage}" alt=""></a>  
          
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto py-4 py-md-0">
              <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">${authenticatedUser?.lastName} ${authenticatedUser?.firstName}</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-uri="/logout">Se déconnecter</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`;



  const navbar = document.querySelector('#navbarWrapper');

  navbar.innerHTML = isAuthenticated() ? authenticatedUserNavbar : anonymousUserNavbar;

  const logo = document.querySelector('.navbar-brand')
  logo.addEventListener('click', () => {
    Navigate('/');
  });

  const adjustHeaderOnScroll = () => {
    const header = $('.start-style');
    $(window).scroll(() => {
      const scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll >= 10) {
        header.removeClass('start-style').addClass('scroll-on');
      } else {
        header.removeClass('scroll-on').addClass('start-style');
      }
    });
  };
  
  const setupMenuHoverEffect = () => {
    $('body').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.nav-item', (e) => {
      if ($(window).width() > 750) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
        const _d = $(e.target).closest('.nav-item');
        _d.addClass('show');
        setTimeout(() => {
          _d[_d.is(':hover') ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('show');
        }, 1);
      }
    });
  };
  

  
  const initializeApp = () => {
    adjustHeaderOnScroll();
    setupMenuHoverEffect();
  };
  
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    initializeApp();
  });
}

export default Navbar;
```

it's the dropdown item that doesn't show up when a reload but when i login for the first time it's appear

that is the code of Router

```
import { removePathPrefix, usePathPrefix } from '../../utils/path-prefix';
import routes from './routes';

const Router = () => {
  onFrontendLoad();
  onNavBarClick();
  onHistoryChange();
};

function onNavBarClick() {
  const navbarWrapper = document.querySelector('#navbarWrapper');

  navbarWrapper.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const navBarItemClicked = e.target;
    const uri = navBarItemClicked?.dataset?.uri;
    if (uri) {
      const componentToRender = routes[uri];
      if (!componentToRender) throw Error(`The ${uri} ressource does not exist.`);

      componentToRender();
      window.history.pushState({}, '', usePathPrefix(uri));
    }
  });
}

function onHistoryChange() {
  window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
    const uri = removePathPrefix(window.location.pathname);
    const componentToRender = routes[uri];
    componentToRender();
  });
}

function onFrontendLoad() {
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const uri = removePathPrefix(window.location.pathname);
    const componentToRender = routes[uri];
    if (!componentToRender) throw Error(`The ${uri} ressource does not exist.`);

    componentToRender();
  });
}

export default Router;
```

Could someone please provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

(It's my first question here so maybe it's not clear. Sorry in advance!)

Comment: Hi. At first read I guess that you have to initiate a new checking of the `token`. Or it is a `cache` problem. 

Comment: Hi. Can you explain to me why I would need to initiate a new checking? Also, could you clarify what a cache problem is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The two things together, the old `token` might be still in the `cache`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache 

Comment: I don't resend a new token in the response. Just the infos of the user. i keep the same token so i don't think that's the problem. Thanks anyway

Comment: Which `navbar` does show? The `authenticated` or `anonymous`? 

Comment: when i go in the website, it's the anonymous with no problem. after i login and the authenticated display with also no problem. but after i refresh i am still connected but the dropdown menu doesn't work anymore and the content of the home page also. And I've noticed that when I refresh multiple times in a row, the homepage displays one out of every five times, but the dropdown menu never appears.